# Javascript Application Adding two numbers with textboxes and showing the result

Tags: javascript

If i save the result in a variable inside the function:

```
var result=document.getElementById('result').value;
result=num1+num2;
```

the result wont show in its textbox.

But if i write:

```
var result=document.getElementById('result');
result.value=num1+num2;
```

then everything is alright. 
Can anyone help me why this is happening??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result` is an instance of a `Number` at a point in time in your first snippet. There's nothing watching the change of `result` and associating it back to the element it came from, so the input field will not be updated.

In your second snippet, you're saving a reference to your `DOMElement`, `#result`, and setting its value, so the text in the field is updated.

Comment: OK.I understand your answer. The only thing that made me mad,was that in the first snippet.when i tried to alert(result') every thing was ok.in the sense that,the right result was shows as an alert in the browser. Anyway ,Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Here `result` is the value of `value`:

```
var result=document.getElementById('result').value;
```

Here `result.value` is a reference to `value`:

```
var result=document.getElementById('result');
```